# Install windows using built-in Administrator

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, administrator

I want to use the Windows 10 Administrator account from the beginning while installing and skip the creation of a (temporary) account. I can activate the Administrator account during the Windows 10 installation process with this method.

1. When prompted for username just hit SHIFT+F10
2. CMD should open
3. Use "net user Administrator /ACTIVE:YES"

And now I'm stuck. I tried opening taskmgr.exe and stop the MS account executable  without any luck and forcing the installation restart from the language/keyboard etc. part.

Does anyone know a way that doesn't require an account (doesn't matter if temporary or for daily uses)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can boot into System Audit Mode.

System Audit Mode is a bit of a special mode - it's used by OEMs (original equipment manufacturers) when they're trying to load software onto their computers before they capture an image of them. It's used, for example, to go in after a system has been sysprepped (that is to say, generalized with the system-unique info removed) and modify the image without using tools such as DISM. This mode will automatically reboot the system and log you in using the local admin account, as well as launch a program called sysprep (though you can just close this).

You can boot into System Audit Mode by using Ctrl + Shift + F3 key combination at the OOBE/system initial set-up screen.

Let me know if this works for you! Note that the system will reset back to OOBE on every boot, but you should just be able to go back into System Audit Mode. Note also that this isn't really meant for general use, but to my knowledge, there's not any significant limitations (i.e. your profile gets wiped on every reboot) that would discourage such use. If I'm wrong, though, someone can correct me.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know I could do this while installing. Even after installing a few apps (VLC, Gimp...) and changing some settings it looks like it didn't lose anything! I'm going to try to find out if it's possible to hide the GUI at startup.

Comment: The Sysprep GUI? Wow, I'd have no idea where the instruction to launch that would be stored. Good luck! Feel free to mark my answer as correct if it helped you! It may also help you to go ahead and do the net user Administrator /active:yes command as well, as sys audit mode keeps the admin account disabled and just bypasses that block.